Access `http.port` for integration test launched interactively in open liberty dev mode
PROBLEM SOLVED -- FOR SOME REASONS ITS NOT OCCURRING ANYMORE

My JEE OpenLiberty integration tests should look up the port and application context root dynamically, such as:
    String port = System.getProperty("http.port");
    String context = System.getProperty("context.root");

This works fine when running the test from Intellij. Somehow (maven-failsafe-plugin?) the variables in my pom.xml file make it into the VM and are available for lookup in the test.
Now when I trigger running tests in "dev mode" by pressing ENTER once the server has started both properties return null.
How can I fix this?
----------- EDIT: ----------
These are my pom.xml properties:
   <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <liberty.var.http.port>9080</liberty.var.http.port>
        <liberty.var.https.port>9443</liberty.var.https.port>
        <liberty.var.app.context.root>myapp</liberty.var.app.context.root>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

and this my failsafe configuration:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <http.port>${liberty.var.http.port}</http.port>
                        <app.context.root>${liberty.var.app.context.root}</app.context.root>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


Can you share enough of your pom.xml to show how the properties might get set?  E.g. your  and your failsafe configuration?

@ScottKurz done, please see above

Sorry folks, its working now. No idea why

You can set the values for variables used in the server.xml using Maven properties. These can be set in the pom.xml or passed on the command line. See the documentation here for how properties that start with 'liberty.var' get set in the server in the target directory.
<properties>
    <liberty.var.http.port>9080</liberty.var.http.port>
</properties>


Also, if you look at this Open Liberty guide (https://openliberty.io/guides/rest-intro.html#running-the-application), you can see it using the Maven properties to set both the http.port and the app.context.root and setting the following in the maven-failsafe-plugin configuration.
                <systemPropertyVariables>

                    <http.port>${liberty.var.http.port}</http.port>

                    <context.root>${liberty.var.app.context.root}</context.root>

                </systemPropertyVariables>


Yes, I know that. Did you read that I am struggling with the case that this does not work when running tests from within the server running in dev-mode?

Sorry, its working now...
